# find and remove common substring with python

Tags: python, substring, bioinformatics

So I have a two primer sequences:

```
fiveprime = "GATTCGAAGTCCACTATC"
threeprime = "TGAGTAGGACGGCACTATC"
```

What I need to do is when I have another sequence I need to check if it contains a part 
of one these primer sequences and if it does I need to remove the matching part leaving the non-matching part for further analysis.

For example my sequence: **CACTATC**AAAAAAA
has a part of the fiveprimer in it. I need to locate this common substring and then remove it leaving only the `AAAAA`.

The problem I run in to is when you have a sequence like this **CACTATC**GAAG where GAAG is also in the primer, but not part of the primer sequence it's still removed. I tried to fix this by making sure that the found structure is at the left side of the primer and with the threeprimer on the right side so example:

With the **CACTATC**GAAG we have 2 common structures **CACTATC** and **GAAG**
now I can compare **CACTATC** with the end of the fiveprime GATTCGAAGTC**CACTATC** and tell it's part of the primer when it's a match and then remove it. So when we compare **GAAG** with the length of the last end of the fiveprimer it will give us this GATTCGAAGTCCAC**TATC** which is not a match so **GAAG** can go on for further analysis.

For some reason my script bugs or doesn't work properly. Are there any other solutions to this problem or suggestions?

```
def longestSubstringFinder(string1, string2):
answer = ""
len1, len2 = len(string1), len(string2)
for i in range(len1):
    match = ""
    for j in range(len2):
        if i + j < len1 and string1[i + j] == string2[j]:
            match += string2[j]
        else:
            if len(match) > len(answer): answer = match
            match = ""
return answer

def get_sequence(test, fiveprime, threeprime):
    if test == fiveprime:
        pass
    elif test == threeprime:
        pass
    elif test in fiveprime:
        pass
    elif test in threeprime:
        pass

        # find out if there is a matching part between the primers and the found
        # single stranded region, then calculates what part that is, and removes it
        # from the single stranded region
    else:
        overlap = longestSubstringFinder(fiveprime, test)
        l = len(overlap)

        if fiveprime[-l:] == test[:l]:
            check = test[l:]
        else:
            check = test

        overlap2 = longestSubstringFinder(check, threeprime)
        l = len(overlap2)

        if threeprime[:l] == check[-l:]:
            check2 = check[:-l]
            structure.append(check2)
        else:
            structure.append(check)

return structure
```

Comment: What is the length of the string you much match?

Comment: You didn't define the `structure` variable anywhere, but you're happily appending to it.

Comment: depends on the string i input, can be any length. thats why i check the  length of the found common substring. and then use that to compare if the found structure is part of the primer

Comment: haha yeah soz about the strucure i just coppied and pasted the code stucture is defined as structure = [] just your normal list

Comment: what is considered 'part of' the primers? how many characters must be a match?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing in the `get_sequence` function. You're finding the longest shared sequence `overlap`. Then you save the length of `overlap` into `l`. And then you compare the last `l` characters in `fiveprime` to the first `l` characters in `test`. Shouldn't you be comparing it to `overlap`?

Comment: yeah thats true but when i just these settings:     test = "AATTAAGAATGAGTCTGTGGCACTATC"

    threeprime = "TGAGTCTGTGGCACTATC"
    fiveprime = "GATCCTACACGCACTATC" it fails i dont know why :S

Comment: the 1 = L is from length

Comment: What's the expected output for `get_sequence('CACTATCGAAG', 'GATTCGAAGTCCACTATC', 'TGAGTAGGACGGCACTATC')` and `get_sequence('AATTAAGAATGAGTCTGTGGCACTATC', 'GATCCTACACGCACTATC', 'TGAGTCTGTGGCACTATC')`?

Comment: first one should return: GAAG second one should return: AATTAAGAA

Comment: Why aren't you using one of the many well tested and heavily used primer trimmer programs out there?  You don't have to re-invent the wheel.  Also you must check for reverse complement hits

Comment: im not simply trimming the primers of my fasta file, i did search for existing programms but couldnt find them. i predict single stranded region's of aptamer sequences for motif analysis. i need to do this with the primers attacked because they influence the folding structure. then i extract the single stranded sequences, but if they contain a part of the primer that part needs to be removed. because i want to find a motif, and it doenst do much good to find a motif in the primer sequences xDDDD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem will be more tractable if you select the appropriate data structure to represent the data you are trying to find. The best one I can think of is a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

The benefit of this structure is that it allows you to represent all of the possible matches given an initial sequence of letters, so if you have the sequence AABAB it will allow traversal from an initial A to both A and B, but not traversal from A to G or T. This makes it efficient to find partial matches, as any point in the trie represents a match of that many letters.

This data structure will be something like:

```
class Trie(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}

    def add_child(self, letter):
        if letter in self.children:
            return self.children[letter]
        else:
            child = Trie()
            self.children[letter] = child
            return child

    def traverse(self, letter):
        return self.children.get(letter, None)
```

You can then populate this like so:

```
root = Trie()
current_positions = []
for letter in letters:
    current_positions = [
        position.add_child(letter)
        for position in current_positions
    ]
    current_positions.append(root.add_child(letter))
```

Once all of this is set up you should then be able to traverse this structure until the traversal returns null. This will indicate the longest current match. The initialization of the letters treats each letter as a potential starting point of a match, and so should you.

You can then search for longest substring matches like so:

```
class TrieSearch(object):
    def __init__(self, trie, starting_index):
        self.trie = trie
        self.starting_index = starting_index
        self.ending_index = starting_index + 1

    def update(self, letter):
        """ This returns a boolean indicating
            if the search can accept the letter """
        self.trie = self.trie.traverse(letter)
        if self.trie is not None:
            self.ending_index = self.ending_index + 1
            return True
        return False

    def get_match(self, letters):
        return letters[self.starting_index:self.ending_index]

def find_matches(root, letters):
    completed_matches = []
    current_matches = []

    for index, letter in enumerate(letters):
        new_current = []

        for current in current_matches:
            if current.update(letter):
                new_current.append(current)
            else:
                completed_matches.append(current)

        new_search_trie = root.traverse(letter)
        if new_search_trie is not None:
            new_current.append(TrieSearch(new_search_trie, index))

        current_matches = new_current

    all_matches = completed_matches + current_matches
    return [match.get_match(letters) for match in all_matches]
```

I have put all of this together in [a gist](https://gist.github.com/matthewfranglen/64e417598355f811d900) and when the trie is initialized with the `threeprime` and `fiveprime` values and the input data is `CACTATCAAAAAAA` the results are:

```
['CACTATC', 'ACTATC', 'CTATC', 'TATC', 'ATC', 'TC', 'CA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'A']
```

Since you are no doubt dealing with massive strings, you may want to review some of the more efficient general string substitution algorithms. The [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) is an extension of the trie approach outlined here. There is also the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) which uses tables instead of the trie. Both of these are linear complexity algorithms which will be a substantial improvement over the quadratic approach that your `longestSubstringFinder` approach uses.

Comment: im going to give this a try, i will tell if a succeeded or not. Thanks for your input and your time!!

Comment: I have put the code samples together in a gist, you may want to review that.

Comment: this is to good, Thanks a lot man you realy helped me out. also looks a lot nicer then my code xD

Comment: if you want your code to be better then practice, practice, practice :) You might want to check out the book 'Clean Code' for tips: http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `longestSubstringFinder` is broken. You're checking `if len(match) > len(answer): answer = match` **only** if the condition `if len(match) > len(answer): answer = match` is `False`. If the `for j in range(len2):` loop ends without that happening, you simply discard the `match`.

The fix is simple: add `for j in range(len2):` after the `for j in range(len2):` loop.

```
def longestSubstringFinder(string1, string2):
    answer = ""
    len1, len2 = len(string1), len(string2)
    for i in range(len1):
        match = ""
        for j in range(len2):
            if i + j < len1 and string1[i + j] == string2[j]:
                match += string2[j]
            else:
                if len(match) > len(answer): answer = match
                match = ""
        if len(match) > len(answer): answer = match # this was missing
    return answer
```

Comment: i will check this first thing tomorrow thanks a lot for your time and input.